# Connect to Azure Redis Cache using Java with Jedis Library

Tags: java, azure, redis, jedis

I am trying to connect to Azure Redis Cache using Jedis library version 3.7.0 Using below java code.

Not able to make the connection and instead getting below jedisConnectionException

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host xxxxx-azure.redis.cache.windows.net:63

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

```
        JedisShardInfo   shardInfo = new JedisShardInfo("xxxxx-azure.redis.cache.windows.net",6379, true);
        shardInfo.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        Jedis jedis = new Jedis(shardInfo);
 
        String pingResponse = jedis.ping();
        System.out.println("ping should return pong" + pingResponse);
```

can anyone please give me some input on what is the configuration that I am missing or doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you're trying to connect to your Redis Cache instance on a non-SSL port (6379) which is blocked by default for Azure Redis Cache instances.

You can try to connect to the SSL port (6380) or enable non-SSL port for your Redis Cache. You can change that setting in Azure Portal.